# How to access Qt Build System project (QBS) variables in Qt code

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qbs

Good day.

I need to access specific QBS variables inside my Qt code.

An example is the Application's name, organisation or even the flavour, all variables specified like this in my application qbs file.

```
import qbs

Project {

    // These variables should be available in C++ code.
    name: "my_app_name"
    organization: "Organisation_Name"
    flavour:"AppFlavour"
    minimumQbsVersion: "1.7.1"

    CppApplication {
        files: [
        ]
        Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: ['core', 'network'] }

        cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"

        cpp.defines: [
            "QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS",
        ]

        consoleApplication: true

        Group {
            name: "source"
            files: [
                "qconfigurationmanager.cpp",
            ]
        }

        Group {
            name: "header"
            files: [
                "qconfigurationmanager.h",
            ]
        }

        Group {     // Properties for the produced executable
            fileTagsFilter: "application"
            qbs.install: true
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the Qt documentation for [QBS](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/), I did not find any reference to using QBS variables in Qt code.

[This](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32981/solved-system-environment-variables-in-qbs/2) is the only link of using QBS variables, but only within the QBS file

I would like to do this:

```
QString appflavour = Qbs.get("flavour")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible option is to use a DEFINES and obtain the data through a macro:

```
import qbs

Project {
    minimumQbsVersion: "1.7.1"

    property string name: "my_app_name"
    property string organization: "Organisation_Name"
    property string flavour:"AppFlavour"

    CppApplication {
        Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: ['core', 'network']}
        cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"
        consoleApplication: true

        cpp.defines: [
            "QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS",
            "name=" + project.name,
            "organization=" +  project.organization,
            "flavour=" + project.flavour
        ]
...
```

---

```
#define QUOTE_(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x) QUOTE_(x)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString appname = QUOTE(name);
    QString organization = QUOTE(organization);
    QString appflavour = QUOTE(flavour);

    qDebug()<< appname << organization << appflavour;

...
```

Output:

```
"my_app_name" "Organisation_Name" "AppFlavour"
```